# angular-route dependency not requiring

Tags: angularjs, routes, npm

With the new angular-route version, you need to `require('angular-route')` in your dependencies but I can't seem to get this working. In the [angular-route npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-route), it says to do `angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-route')]);`

This is my code:

```
angular.module('app.routes', [require('angular-route')])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

When I run my server, I get the error: `require is not defined`.

Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) if you want to use **require** in frontend.

Browserify is a node module that takes your main JavaScript file, read all its required dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies), and spits out a single JavaScript file, ready to be included in your HTML. This file contains JavaScript code that is actually compatible with browsers, in other words, it browserfies your Node modules.

Also you can see the following link how he structure the angular js with browserify

http://omarfouad.com/blog/2015/03/21/advanced-angularjs-structure-with-gulp-node-and-browserify/

Other wise you need to use the following code snippet.

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: The last time I did this was about 4 months ago and you would just link the angular-route file before your app.js in your index.html and then in your app.js, you would just call: `angular.module('app_name', ['ngRoute'])...`. How come you cannot do that anymore?

Comment: you r right. if you want to use angular with node js then browserify is required, other than that you can do that `angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute']);` in your app js and include app.js in your html file after angular.js and angular-route.js file. you can see the following link for more clearance
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: I figured out the problem... all I had to do was include my service file and controller file

Answer (score 1):

You should use the dependency injection as normally:

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['angular-route']);
```

Remember that you need to load the angular-route module before you load your app.js.

require is from [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Actually, when I asked the question, it had been a while since I used Angular and my problem was that the `angular-route` dependency is actually injected as `ngRoute`, not `angular-route`.